# How do we remove special characters from a string from a particular position in java?

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I have a scenario where i have to remove special characters from a string.

Input String : `name=/"xyz =bcd .olm --=myname/"`

Output String Must be Like: `name=/"xyz bcd olm myname/"`

I tried something like below and still not able to come up with the exact regex. Can anyone help me to figure out what i have done wrong?

```
    String inputString = "name=\"xyz =bcd .olm --=myname\"";
    String regex = "(?<=name=\")[^<]*(?<!/)(\\w+)(?=[^>]*>)";
    String outputString = inputString.replaceAll(regex, "$1");

    System.out.println(outputString);
```

Comment: *i have to remove special characters from a string* How do you define *special characters*?

Comment: I am sorry. to be specific, it is nonalphanumeric chars

Comment: I tried with [^a-zA-Z0-9] which removes the entire alphanumeric chars from the string but the thing is i have to keep few nonalphanumeric chars in the begining and end of the string. I am very new to regex.

Comment: Is regex a requirement, or do you only want a solution for replacing the special character?

Comment: regex is the requirement, Jens

Comment: is `name="` a fix string?

Comment: yeah the string will have name=/" ************** /" . The * are the chars where non alphanumerics has to be removed

Comment: Not a Java Expert, but this works on regex101: `[^\w/\" ](?!(?:.*\/\"){2})`: https://regex101.com/r/WotO4b/latest

Comment: Thanks for your effort DuesserBaest. Will try to modify your regex.

Answer (score 2):

For the replacement. You need to first get the content value of name field. Then you can remove special characters from the string.

Example code block:

```
    String line = "name=\"xyz =bcd .olm --=myname\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"(.*)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String nameString = matcher.group(1);
        String newNameString = nameString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
        String result = line.replace(nameString, newNameString);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Result prints as `name="xyz bcd olm myname"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
inputString.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|name=\")([^\"\\p{Punct}]*)\\p{Punct}(?=[^\"]*\")", "$1$2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/781cca/1)

The regex matches

- `(\G(?!^)|name=\")` - Group 1: `name="` or the end of the preceding successful match
- `([^\"\p{Punct}]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `"` and punctuation chars
- `\p{Punct}` - any punctuation chars
- `(?=[^\"]*\")` - immediately from the current position to the right, there must be any zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char.